# What is a good free program to open corrupted JPEG files?

Tags: windows, gratis, images, photography

Back story: I have about 15 photos (JPEG) that are corrupted files on a computer after accidentally deleting them on a SD. I have recovered them using *Recuva*, and tried *[File Repair](http://www.filerepair1.com/)* to open the corrupted files with no luck. **The thumbnails display for all of them, but when opening with a variety of applications, the computer freezes.**

Here is what I want:

1. **It has to work.** This one is kinda obvious, but it is the most important feature. Chances is I will not use this application after the images are repaired.
2. **Free!** (Bonus points for open source!) I've seen many paid products online, but I don't want to buy them if they don't work.
3. **Batches:** I don't want to individually import all of the files and wait. Ideally, it won't change files that aren't corrupted so I can select the whole folder and take a nap.
4. **A decent GUI:** I don't need anything fancy, but I've seriously seen applications for this that look like the image below:

   http://www.liketobattle.com/thumb.php?src=http://www.liketobattle.com/images/uploads/647469264Screen%20shot%202010-11-04%20at%20%20copy.PNG&w=325&h=230&zc=1

(This software is needed for a friend who uses **Windows XP SP3 32bit**: I personally use Windows 8.1)

I don't mind if I can only open them in that one program: I can take a screenshot and edit some EXIF data. To open I've used MS Picture Manager, GIMP, Paint, and the included Photo viewer.

Comment: This sounds like a one-time issue for only 15 pics. You'd have to check if it is on-topic there, but maybe you can just upload the files somewhere and then on superuser.com ask if anyone can fix them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wikimedia [recommends](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aSoftware#JPEG) using [JpegSnoop](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html).

1. Whether this works depends on your images, but Wikimedia claims it can uncorrupt Jpegs, so presumably it works for some people..
2. Yes, it's open source.
3. Batches, I didn't see support for this, though you could just write a batch file for your friend to drag to.
4. The UI isn't so-so.  It does support drag and drop, among other things.

Windows XP support - I know some of the versions support XP, but I'm not completely sure if that's true of the current version.

Comment: I got JpegSnoop to open my jpeg and I can see it at the bottom, but how do you actually save the file in an uncorrupted format? Export Jpeg seems to export a file that I can't open, and the documentation implies you use "save log" but that saves a text file.

Comment: I managed to save it by exporting as a TIFF then converting that in another program to a jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

Check DiskTuna. You may first want to try recovering the files again using different software. It is not unlikely for photo and video on a SD card or similar to be fragmented. JPEG Recovery LAB is often able to recover these intact where other software fails.

Also, files on a SD card often share a common header which fact can be used to repair corrupt files using the intact ones. JPG-Repair from DiskTuna works this way.

Hope this may help someone although probably too late for OP.

Answer (score 1):

I personally used Stellar Repair for Photo software for corrupt images But it's not free. The free version of this software only shows the preview of repair files once you download the repair files you need to purchase the software. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think it is difficult to open corrupted JPEG files.  Available tools can retrieve files that are only in good conditions. Retrieve files in bad conditions is a 50-50 chance. This is because they are over written by some other files. I will suggest you 2 methods.

- I had used Recuva several times.

Other tools like Recuva:

1. EASEUS Data Recovery Wizard Free Edition 7.5
2. MiniTool Power Data Recovery Free Edition 6.8
3. Pandora Recovery 2.2.1
4. Paragon Backup & Recovery 2014 10.1.21.287
5. Wise Data Recovery 3.44

If you are trying to install these, don't install it in the drive from which the images are deleted.

- Try some image converter tools like 'Format Factory 3.34'. Just try to convert the corrupted file to any other image file type. If it works, you are lucky.

Comment: The OP is already past this stage (unless he made a bitwise copy of the damaged medium and recovered *that*)